# Stop EditText from gainning focus when another EditText clear focus

Tags: android, focus

In my activity, I got a few EditText. When I remove the focus from one of theme and make it non focusable, the focus is given to another EditText. I remove the focus this way :

```
atxtTag.setFocusable(false);
atxtTag.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
atxtTag.clearFocus();
```

I don't what to transfer the focus on another EditText. I tried to achieve this by setting the focus on another view after removing the focus from the first element. So I put the focus on the main layout witch is a ScrollView but it didn't work.

How can I achieve to remove the focus on one EditText without transferring it on another EditText?

Thank you.

Comment: You would need to put the focus on some other focusable widget. A `ScrollView` is not focusable.

Answer (score 3):

The `clearFocus` method [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/View.java#View.clearFocus%28%29) does the `clearFocusInternal` call passing `true` as the value of the `refocus` argument. That leads to request focus for first focusable element. So, a possible solution could be to make a call of `clearFocusInternal(true, false);` through reflection, but I haven't actually check that.

Digging into the `requestFocus` [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/View.java#6995) I found it checks `DescendantFocusability` of the root view. Using that I've built a working solution:

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) atxtTag.getRootView();
int dfValue = rootView.getDescendantFocusability();
rootView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
atxtTag.clearFocus();
rootView.setDescendantFocusability(dfValue);
```

Additionally, clearing of the focus doesn't hide software keyboard, so you might need to hide it as well:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(atxtTag.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the manifest file :

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: If I understand, I have to put android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" on each EditText in xml. Is that right?

Comment: Correct, that should prevent the EditText from being focussed upon